# How to have an image next to a text in html

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

i want to recreate a site (https://trash.clothing/) and iam very new to coding HTML and CSS (overall coding)
and now i want to recreate the shopping cart icon with the "cart" text.

so i already deleted the code xD but i normally added a "div" and in the "div" the cart image with a class, then i changed the height and width in the css code. after that i added a paragraph for the "cart" text (you can see it on the original site what i mean). then i modified the "div" class with float: right so that they are horizontally aligned but that didnt worked, they were like stacked or idk very weird aligned and there is my problem.
I will put my code down without the code that i deleted because i deleted it hahah.
my code(html,css):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/source-sans-pro"
      rel="stylesheet"
      <link
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="imgMain">
      <img src="img/trash-logo.avif" class="MainImg" />
    </div>
    <div class="navigator">
      <ul style="text-align: center">
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>FAQ & Contact</li>
        <li>Trash Gang</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/source-sans-pro');


.MainImg {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 10%;
    height: auto;
padding-top: 80px;
max-width: 200px;
position:relative ;
}
.navigator{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;                      
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.14286em;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Display: flex` is used to put multiple elements next to each other so it should help you align those two elements. If this solution is somewhat similar to what you expected, replace the `<div class="image">` with your shopping cart image and you should be good !

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.container .image{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <p>Cart</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ill try it later, then i will tell you the results, thank you for commenting :)

Comment: worked perfectly fine!